# java :Logic operaction in Catch statment

Tags: java

I have recently noticed at the code that Eclipse generate it automatically and i could not understand it?

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e)  {......}
```

What does that mean `ClassNotFoundException | IOException e`?

Is  the `e` object finally an instance of class  `ClassNotFoundException`  or `IOException`?

Comment: it's a catch statement. what is in that block, will be executed if either a ClassNotFoundException or an IOException is thrown within the try block

Comment: @Stultuske dont answer in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a catch statement. what is in that block, will be executed if either a ClassNotFoundException or an IOException is thrown

In releases prior to Java SE 7, it is difficult to create a common method to eliminate the duplicated code because the variable ex has different types.

The following example, which is valid in Java SE 7 and later, eliminates the duplicated code:

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
logger.log(ex);
throw ex;
}
```

The catch clause specifies the types of exceptions that the block can handle, and each exception type is separated with a vertical bar (|).

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Comment: And this syntax is just usable in Catch statments?

Comment: yes ,It is added to  eliminate the duplicated code , new version of try is introduced in java 7, have a look , you no need to use finally block  http://www.mkyong.com/java/try-with-resources-example-in-jdk-7/

Comment: out of my curiosity, what is wrong in the question? i got "-1"?

Comment: I dont know , but you should have Googled before asking